# went on vs went

Tags: word-usage

I have a question about 'went on vs went' . What is difference between them in these two sentences?

- They went on their honeymoon to Italy
- They went their honeymoon to Italy.

Are they both correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Go" (in the sense of moving) is intransitive, so your second sentence is ungrammatical because "honeymoon" is a direct object.

Comment: This question is unsuitable for ELU.

Answer (score 0):

I have never met the second construction. It is plain wrong, for the reasons others have set out. "They went mad" is a valid construction but is not a model for "They went honeymoon".